# Listen to Stream and write only once to DB in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, qr-code, sqflite

I'm developing a QR code reader app and I use an external QR reader package (https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner).
It listens to a Stream and returns QR data. But when I write the data to sqlite database it writes the same data several times because it doesn't stop listening to Stream. I dont think unsubscribing from stream is a good idea because i still need the stream to listen after coming back from a url launch or closing the dialog. Please correct me if I'm wrong and suggest a solution, Thank You.

```
void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) async {
      
      setState(() {
        qrData = scanData;
      });
  
      if (await canLaunch(qrData)) {
        var status = await launch(qrData);

        if(status){
          final data = QrModel(
            content: scanData,
            date: DateFormat.yMMMd().add_jm().format(DateTime.now()),
          );
          await dbProvider.addData(data);
        }

      } else {

        if (!alertBoxOpen) {

          final data = QrModel(
            content: scanData,
            date: DateFormat.yMMMd().add_jm().format(DateTime.now()),
          );
          await dbProvider.addData(data);

          setState(() => alertBoxOpen = true);
          
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  content: Text(qrData),
                  actions: [
                    MaterialButton(
                        child: Text('OK',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() => alertBoxOpen = false);
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        }),
                  ],
                );
              });
        }
      }
    });
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a workaround for this. I assigned the value returned from stream which is `scanData` to the variable `qrData` and added to DB if `qrData != scanData`

```
void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;

    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) async {
      if (await canLaunch(scanData)) {
        await launch(scanData);

        if (qrData != scanData) {
          setState(() {
            qrData = scanData;
          });
          final data = QrModel(
            content: scanData,
            date: DateFormat.yMMMd().add_jm().format(DateTime.now()),
          );
          await dbProvider.addData(data);
        }
      } else {
        if (!alertBoxOpen) {
          if (qrData != scanData) {
            setState(() {
              qrData = scanData;
            });
            final data = QrModel(
              content: scanData,
              date: DateFormat.yMMMd().add_jm().format(DateTime.now()),
            );
            await dbProvider.addData(data);
          }

          setState(() => alertBoxOpen = true);

          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  content: Text(qrData),
                  actions: [
                    MaterialButton(
                        child: Text('OK',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() => alertBoxOpen = false);
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        }),
                  ],
                );
              });
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a single subscription on stream or is it that the stream emits multiple same values? If it is the latter I suggest you try [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) package. It is an implementation of ReactiveX for Dart. I am not that much experienced in reactive programming, but in my experience when I  used `BehaviorSubject` from rxdart it didn't notify subscribers when the same value was added to it. So one thing you could do is to add each value from the QR Stream to `BehaviorSubject`, and instead subscribe (listen) to behavior subject for making queries to database.

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with rxdart, can you please elaborate more on how to implement this solution?

Comment: @Dulanka After going through rxdart docs I found the `distinct` method [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject/distinct.html). It's implementation uses `distinct` method of Dart's Stream. So, you probably don't need rxdart. Just call `.distinct()` on the stream before you listen to it. But this will work only if the stream emits multiple same values. Not if there are multiple subscriptions

Comment: Thanks for your effort! This function is really helpful. But the user cannot scan the same QR again because the stream won't allow equal values.

Comment: @Dulanka The user should be able to scan the same QR code after scanning a different QR code. After all, you said you don't want same event to happen twice or more in a row. Are you sure you are subscribing only once?